# SLICK: To insert value in 3 different tables using one slick api call

Tags: scala, slick, scalaquery

The question is related to slick:
I have three tables:
1) Users
2)Team2members
3)Team2Owners

In my post request to users, I am passing values of `memberOf` and `managerOf`, these values will be inserted in the tables `Team2members` and `Team2Owners` respectively and not in Users table. Though other values of the post request will be inserted in 'Users' table.

My Post request looks like below:

```
{"kind": "via#user",
      "userReference":{"userId":"priya16"},
      "user":"preferredNameSpecialChar@domain1.com","memberOf":{"teamReference":{"organizationId":"airtel","teamId":"supportteam"}},
       "managerOf":{"teamReference":{"organizationId":"airtel","teamId":"supportteam"}},
      "firstName":"Special_fn1",
      "lastName":"specialChar_ln1",
      "preferredName":[{"locale":"employee1","value":"@#$%^&*(Z0FH"}],
      "description":" preferredNameSpecialChar test "}
```

I am forming the query which is shown below:
The query seems to work fine when only `memberInsert` is defined, when I try to define both the values i.e.`memberInsert` and `managerInsert` then insertion happens only for second value.

```
val query = config.api.customerTableDBIO(apiRequest.parameters.organizationId).flatMap { tables =>
      val userInsert = tables.Users returning tables.Users += empRow
      val memberInsert = inputObject.memberOf.map(m => m.copy(teamReference = m.teamReference.copy(organizationId = apiRequest.parameters.organizationId))).map { r =>
        for {
          team2MemberRow <- tables.Team2members returning tables.Team2members += Teams2MembersEntity.fromEmtToTeams2Members(r, empRow.id)
          team <- tables.Teams.filter(_.id === r.teamReference.teamId.toLowerCase).map(_.friendlyName).result.headOption
        } yield (team2MemberRow, team)
      }
      val managerInsert = inputObject.managerOf.map(m => m.copy(teamReference = m.teamReference.copy(organizationId = apiRequest.parameters.organizationId))).map { r =>
        for {
          team2OwnerRow <- tables.Team2owners returning tables.Team2owners += Teams2OwnersEntity.fromEmtToTeam2owners(r, empRow.id)
          team <- tables.Teams.filter(_.id === r.teamReference.teamId.toLowerCase).map(_.friendlyName).result.headOption
        } yield (team2OwnerRow, team)
      }

      userInsert.flatMap { userRow =>
        val user = UserEntity.fromDbEntity(userRow)
        if (memberInsert.isDefined) memberInsert.get
          .map(r => user.copy(memberOf = Some(Teams2MembersEntity.fromEmtToMemberRef(r._1, r._2.map(TeamEntity.toApiFriendlyName).getOrElse(List.empty)))))
        else DBIO.successful(user)
        if (managerInsert.isDefined) managerInsert.get
          .map(r => user.copy(managerOf = Some(Teams2OwnersEntity.fromEmtToManagerRef(r._1, r._2.map(TeamEntity.toApiFriendlyName).getOrElse(List.empty)))))
        else DBIO.successful(user)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The query seems to work fine when only memberInsert is defined, when I try to define both the values i.e.memberInsert and managerInsert then insertion happens only for second value.

The problem looks to be with the final call to `flatMap`.

That should return a `DBIO[T]`. However, your expression generates a `DBIO[T]` in various branches, but only one value will be returned from `flatMap`. That would explain why you don't see all the actions being run.

Instead, what you could do is assign each step to a value and sequence them. There are [lots of ways you could do that](https://books.underscore.io/essential-slick/essential-slick-3.html#combining), such as using `DBIO.seq` or `andThen`.

Here's a sketch of one approach that might work for you....

```scala
val maybeInsertMemeber: Option[DBIO[User]] =
  member.map( your code for constructing an action here )

val maybeInsertManager Option[DBIO[User]] =
  manager.map( your code for constructing an action here )

DBIO.sequenceOption(maybeInsertMember) andThen
  DBIO.sequenceOption(maybeInsertManager) andThen
  DBIO.successful(user)
```

The result of that expression is a `DBIO[User]` which combines three queries together.